# retrieve user based on child keys

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data structure `https://<app name>.firebaseio.com/options` as:

```
{
    'abc123': {},
    'efg456': {}
}
```

And a `https://<app name>.firebaseio.com/users` as:

```
{
    'test1': {
        options: {'abc123': true}
    },
    'test2': {
        options: {'abc123': true, 'efg456': true}
    }
}
```

I am tying to retrieve an user based on the options he has. The logic would be: `Find <user> where <some option> is found in <user>.<options>`.

I tried something like: `users.orderByChild('options').startAt('abc123').endAt('abc123').on('value', (snapshot) => {});`; But that gives me `null`.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or do I have to structure the data in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to sort by a specific child key (`options/abc123`) and check that the result is `true`;

```
> users.on('value', (snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot.val()) })

{ test1: { options: { abc123: true } },
  test2: { options: { abc123: true, efg456: true } },
  test3: { options: { efg456: true } } }

> users.orderByChild('options/abc123')
       .equalTo(true)
       .on('value', (snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot.val())})

{ test1: { options: { abc123: true } },
  test2: { options: { abc123: true, efg456: true } } }

> users.orderByChild('options/efg456')
       .equalTo(true)
       .on('value', (snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot.val())})

{ test2: { options: { abc123: true, efg456: true } },
  test3: { options: { efg456: true } } }
```

Comment: Is `.startAt(true)` necessary? I don't think it is since I only have that value because I needed the `abc123` as a key so I can do queries easier.

Comment: Actually it looks like it is necessary to add that or `equalTo`, otherwise I do not get the filtered results.

Comment: @rolandjitsu Without startWith or equalTo, it will return all users, all without the key first, then the ones with it.

Comment: I just tried `equalTo` and it seems to return null. `startAt` works as expected.

Comment: @rolandjitsu Hm, I'm getting the correct result with equalTo. Do you have the `true` values quoted by any chance? If so, startAt will work since the string '`true'` sorts after the boolean `true`. Either way, if startAt works for you, I can't see a reason that it would give any worse performance.

Comment: Yeah, I had different values there, some random strings, and I forgot about it. Thanks a lot :)